# I want to RDP to my server that is behind a squid3 proxy

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, proxy, vnc

I want to be able to rdp into my server behind squid3 proxy (on ubuntu).

This is a windows 2000 server and is used for testing. I need it behind a proxy so that it is off my normal network as it is a testing server.

My programmer needs to be able to log into the test server to test updates to the software we use.

How can I get the RDP port to be fwd'd through the proxy to my virtualbox win2k server guest?

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming for the machine that is behind the proxy, that it's only path out to the Internet is via the proxy.  So you are not able to receive incoming connections, and only make outgoing ones through an HTTP proxy.

It's a bit complex, but setting up a VPN via OpenVPN might help.  There are HTTP proxy options for OpenVPN clients which may allow it to connect to an OpenVPN server that you operate outside of the network.

This system that you want to RDP into, you must set it up as an OpenVPN client.  Use the `http-proxy` options as explained [here](http://netwickler.blogspot.com/2012/05/tutorial-connect-openvpn-through-http.html).

On the server side, you'll want to [do this](http://michlstechblog.info/blog/openvpn-set-a-static-ip-address-for-a-client/) (which will require you to set up server and client certificates - [using xca](http://www.carbonwind.net/VPN/XCA_OpenVPN/XCA_OpenVPN.htm) to do this may be easier than following the steps in the [OpenVPN documentation](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html)) to make sure the client, which is the system you want to RDP into, always receives the same VPN IP.

Once both client and server are active and connected, from the server machine which is outside of this network, you ought to be able to `mstsc /v:{VPN-IP}` from the Windows "Run" dialog to reach it.

If you don't want to install OpenVPN on the Win2k server directly, install it on another system behind the proxy on the same network and then once you are RDP'ed into this intermediate system, RDP from there to the WIn2k server.  Windows 7 and 8 handle "cascaded" RDP a bit better than XP IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Squid as transparent proxy and have no need for IPSec you can use iptables to do DNAT.

Suppose the win2k server has the address `10.10.10.10` and uses the standard RDP port this rule should pass the RDP traffic:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:3389
```

If you want extra security you can also specify which interfaces/clients/networks are allowed to connect.

**Examples:**

*only allow eth0*

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:3389
```

*only allow ip 10.10.100.100*

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.10.100.100 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:3389
```

*similarly, only allow connections from a specific network*

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/8 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:3389
```

---

In the unlikely case your win2k server does not have a static ip you need to add this rule also:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

Read up [here](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO.html#toc5) for a very understandable explanation of NAT and DNAT

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work. IPTABLES took the rule, but I still can't rdp into the windows 2000 server. My router has port fwd'ing set to the eth1 ip of the linux computer with squid. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is forwarding enabled? It is not by default, to enable it enter this in your terminal: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward